# Precision is lost while reading a column from excel using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, precision, openpyxl

I'm reading the contents stored in an excel workbook using `load_workbook` of `openpyxl`.
The following is the code,

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=xlsx_file, read_only=True, data_only=True )
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name=sheet)
data = ws.values
columns = next(data)[0:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

I have a column named `t` in excel

[image]

When I print list(df['t']), I get

```
[0.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.7999999999999998, 2.4, 3.0, 3.5999999999999996, 4.2, 4.8, 5.3999999999999995].
```

I would like to know how to avoid the loss of precision.
The same problem occurs when I use

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(xlsx_file, 'rb'), sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
```

Comment: Check the formatting of the cells in the file, it's likely that they are being formatted to one decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the number of digits after the decimal point:

```
df['t'] = df['t'].map('{:,.1f}'.format)
```

Comment: Thank you, we could do this after the dataframe is obtained. I'd like to know if there is anything that can be done to obtain the digits as is while loading.

Comment: Try adding to the read_excel command: float_precision='round_trip'

Comment: But why can't you do it after you load?

Comment: Because the input data might have varying number of digits after the decimal point (2 or 3 or 7 or ..). I don't want to manually look for it every time and set the number of digits. I had tried using read_excel before. When the size of the excel file is large it takes a lot of time to load so I had to switch to load_workbook.